# C program to print combination of 3 letter word

Tags: c

I want to print the combination of any 3 letters without using nested for loop in C programming ?

Following is the code for the combination of 3 letters "ABC". 
I can execute the program by using 3 for loops. 
But I dont want that. I want to do it by only one for loop and in a non-recursive way.But I am not getting any logic.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    int i=0,j=0;
    char b[10],a[] = "ABC";
    strcpy(b,a);
    while(i < 3)
    {
        b[j]=a[i];

        if(i==0)
        {
            b[j+1]=a[i+1];
            b[j+2]=a[i+2];
            printf("\n%s",b);

            b[j+1]=a[i+2];
            b[j+2]=a[i+1];
            printf("\n%s",b);

        }else if(i==1)
        {
            b[j+1]=a[i+1];
            b[j+2]=a[i-1];
            printf("\n%s",b);

            b[j+1]=a[i-1];
            b[j+2]=a[i+1];
            printf("\n%s",b);

        }else
        {
            b[j+1]=a[i-1];
            b[j+2]=a[i-2];
            printf("\n%s",b);

            b[j+1]=a[i-2];
            b[j+2]=a[i-1];
            printf("\n%s",b);
        }

        i++;

    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try using a recursive function?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there is only a statement and no question.

Comment: There is only 1 combination for a 3 letter word. Did you mean permutation?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon, and also the information about why it was put on hold.  Generally, we'll help you fix an honest attempt at coding a solution, but we won't usually write the code for you from the ground up.  Your question is not entirely clear. Do you want to print all combinations of 3 letters from 'aaa' to 'zzz' (but what about upper-case vs lower-case, or accented vs non-accented characters), or do you want to print all permutations of a particular three-letter string (say `"abc"`)?

Comment: I am sorry if the question is not entirely clear. if i have a 3 letter word "abc". Then it should print abc acb bca bac cab cba I am still trying to impliment it.I want to do it with non recursive way and without a nested loop. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does anyone have any answer ?

Answer (score 1):

If you *know* it's always going to be a length of three, you can use pre-generation to minimise complexity and/or code. Pre-generation is the act of moving complex calculations from run time to compile time or even before hand, and it can be very productive for complex calculations.

One example (though a little contrived) is to write a program to calculate all possible unsigned 64-bit factorials (there's only about ninety of them) then have that program generate the *source code* (lookup table and function) that can do the lookup to get them. The complexity of generating the table is done *once,* long before compilation of the program that will use it.

This means that a factorial operation *in the program that uses it,* changes from being a possibly time consuming series of multiplications to something more akin to one multiplication and an addition (the table lookup).

Applying that same method to permutations (though the generation of the lookup table was done in my head since it's not that complex) will give you code like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// The permutations.

static int perm3[] = { 0,1,2,  0,2,1,
                       1,0,2,  1,2,0,
                       2,0,1,  2,1,0 };

int main (void) {
    int i;
    char x[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};

    // Permute using the table to get indexes.

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(perm3) / sizeof(perm3[0]); i += 3)
        printf ("%c %c %c\n", x[perm3[i]], x[perm3[i+1]], x[perm3[i+2]]);

    return 0;
}
```

Now, some people may consider that "cheating" but I'll be honest here, some of the fastest programs you can write will cheat in this manner :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are asking is based of algorithm concept [Backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking)

Here is the function

```
void permute(char *a, int i, int n) 
{
   int j; 
   if (i == n)
     printf("%s\n", a);
   else
   {
        for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
       {
          swap((a+i), (a+j));
          permute(a, i+1, n);
          swap((a+i), (a+j)); //backtrack
       }
   }
}
```

call this from `main()`

```
int main()
{
   char a[] = "ABC";  
   permute(a, 0, 2);     // first param is array,2nd is starting index and 3rd is ending index

   return 0;
}
```

Wolfram alpha is having mathematical concept behind these type of problem.Basically we try all the solutions one by one and then backtrack by reverting those changes to original one and then again try out different solution.To understand clearly check this.
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Permutation.html

Comment: This is correct, but the person who posted the question is looking for a non-recursive solution.

Comment: I thought i might be good to tell about "backtracking" .there is no harm to know something new.

Comment: @shan: What `swap` call does? Is it a inbuilt function (sorry I don know)?